# How to zoom on center with double tap in google map fragment in android studio

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, zooming, double-click, mapfragment

I am new in android studio, I am using google map fragment inside a fragment. i need to zoom exactly on center everytime when double tap on map.
in eclise i used MApView and intercept double tap but i dont know what will i do in android studio.

This is my map fragment.

```
                <fragment
                android:id="@+id/maptrip"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Please any one help me out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Double Click Listener in your MapActivity or  Activity where you implement GoogleMap.This Blog might be helpful for you. [Click Here](http://stillalivedeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-implement-double-click-listener.html)

Comment: Use this mehtod...  `GoogleMap map=mapView.getMap();
map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);`

Comment: I'm not using MapView anywhere. I am usign latest    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.+'

Comment: in this MapView deprecated

Comment: Sunil. Use Mapfragment or Mapview.. You must be use GoogleMap variable for certain methods like zoom . or you can change the version of your library to 9.0.1 instead of 10.0.1. its not effecting to you code or map .